# IIdentityMessageService not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am creating a web application using the asp.net MVC5 with Visual Studio 2013. I installed the sendgrid API into my solution, and created a class that implements the interface `IIdentityMessageService` (actually I am following a tutorial). the problem is, VS keeps saying that the interface could not be found or I am missing an assembly reference. I double checked, I have all the Includes that I need and all the assembly references. I even went to the microsoft site and checked if I was using the correct one. Here's the code:

```
using SendGrid;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;


namespace ESW.Models
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            await configSendGridasync(message);
        }

        // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
        private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
            myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                                "Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S.");
            myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            myMessage.Text = message.Body;
            myMessage.Html = message.Body;

            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                       );

            // Create a Web transport for sending email.
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

            // Send the email.
            if (transportWeb != null)
            {
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
                await Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.iidentitymessageservice(v=vs.108).aspx

That is the page I used to verify the assembly reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while following that tutorial. Thilina De Silva put me on the right track. It's not about the version though, the package is not installed.

this will install the latest version (Use the Package Manager Console)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
```

Answer (score 0):

check your Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin version. You should have minimum 2.1.0 (but better install newset - now it's 2.2.1).

If you have to updated - install it with NuGet:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin -Version 2.2.1
```